# Neo4j 3.0.1 SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE phantom nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In my `Neo4j 3.0.1` and `SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE` project I have a following entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class CriterionGroup extends Authorable {

    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();
....

@NodeEntity
public class Criterion extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private CriterionGroup group;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;
....


@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends Commentable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Decision> parentDecisions = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Decision> childDecisions = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<CriterionGroup> criterionGroups = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();
....
```

In my test I'm trying to delete `CriterionGroup` with a following repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH ()-[r]-(cg:CriterionGroup) WHERE id(cg) = {criterionGroupId} DELETE cg, r")
void deleteCriterionGroup(@Param("criterionGroupId") Long criterionGroupId);
```

then I'm trying to get this `CriterionGroup` by id

```
criterionGroupRepository.findOne(id);
```

and it returns NULL. So far so good.

Right after that I'm trying to get group object from `Criterion` that was in the deleted `CriterionGroup` and it returns.. deleted `CriterionGroup`

```
criterionRepository.findOne(criterion.getId()).getGroup()
```

What am I doing wrong ? Everything worked fine on `SDN 3.4.4.RELEASE` and `Neo4j 2.3.3` but with `Neo4j 3.0.1` `SDN 4.1.1.RELEASE` due to my limited knowledge I have a lot of unexpected situations.

Also, Is it okay to have a following relationship definition in a one entity(I have removed `enforceTargetType` )

```
@Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private Set<Decision> parentDecisions = new HashSet<>();

@Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
private Set<Decision> childDecisions = new HashSet<>();
```

they have different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're having this CriterionGroup re-appear because you deleted it via a custom query, thus bypassing the OGM. The graph knows of your change, but the OGM's mapping context does not.
The solution is to deregister this entity from the session after you've deleted it via a custom query using `Session.detachEntity(id)`, or, refresh the entire session with `session.clear()`.

Yes, it is okay to have the CONTAINS relationship definitions, please remember that for any relationship marked `INCOMING`, you must annotate  accessors, mutators and properties for `parentDecisions` if they exist with `@Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)`

**Update**: Also make sure your object model is in sync with what you're deleting via custom query. i.e. if you're deleting the CriterionGroup via a custom query, you should also update your object model to reflect this i.e. `criterion.group=null`. Or, clear your session completely using `session.clear()` and reload all dependent entities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the proper way for getting a reference to Session object ? Also, for `Decision.parentDecisoins` I have a following methods - `Set<Decision> getParentDecisions()`, `addParentDecision(Decision decision)`, `removeParentDecision(Decision decision)`.. should all of them also be  annotated with `@Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)` ? If so, why do we need such kind of redundancy ?

Comment: I found a way how to access Session. But `session.detachNodeEntity(criterionGroupId);` doesn't work. But `session.clear();` clears all other objects also so all of my existing tests fail.

Comment: Also, do you have a plans to automatically synchronize the state between OGM and custom Cypher query execution ?

Comment: Just the add and get. We'll be revisiting some of the mapping rules in the near future so this should be simplified then. No plans right now to sync state between the ogm and custom queries. Clearing the session should not have affected your tests. When you say detachNodeEntity does not work do you mean you still get the spurious relationship back?

Comment: Yeah, after this method invocation  `@Override
 public void deleteCriterionGroup(Long criterionGroupId) {
  criterionGroupRepository.deleteCriterionGroup(criterionGroupId);
  session.detachNodeEntity(criterionGroupId);
 }` I'm still getting the deleted node back in my test assertion `assertNull(criterionDao.findById(horScalingCriterion.getId()).getGroup());` ... via a reference from another node

Comment: I'm injecting Session into my Spring DAO via `@Autowired private Session session;`

Comment: @brunoid perhaps find us on neo4j-users.slack.com - easier to discuss this via chat

Comment: Thanks, I have sent message to you via slack